# IPv6 not working properly in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet, 20.04, ipv6

Few days ago, I upgraded to latest version of Ubuntu (20.04 LTS). After freshly installing a new system I discovered, that the computer could connect to IPv6 addresses only after a huge timeout. DNS servers are configured properly, ping command finds a correct IPv6 address, but show 100% are lost in first few minutes, then it will magically start working. Sites for testing IPv6 shows that my IPv6 is not working.

The problem is probably caused by a specific combination of both hardware and software. The same version of Ubuntu works on the other devices, and all the other Linux distributions I tried (including Ubuntu 18.04) works without any issues on the same hardware too. I'm currently using Kubuntu 20.04, but the same issue is in default Ubuntu too. It even can be replicated in live USB sessions.

*lspci* command shows I have *RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)*

Obviously, I disabled the IPv6 completely and it solved all connectivity issues I was having. But it still bothers me that the IPv6 is not working for me on the latest version of Ubuntu. What could be causing that? Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: It might be a problem caused by the ipv6 driver in the kernel of ubuntu 20.04.One possible solution is to temporarily use another kernel to see if it gets solved.[This](https://www.tecmint.com/upgrade-kernel-in-ubuntu/) is a guide for installing a custom kernel in ubuntu.

Comment: There'll be an updated binary driver you can download and try, but you could see what is happening with Wireshark, tcpdump or many others.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi No, another kernel is not a solution. I tried both newer and older, but none of them affects the issue in any way.

Comment: @KenSharp Which driver? Where I can find it?

Comment: I have the same problem. Notice when pip stalled. If I disable ipv6 it works fine.